# Measure-agnostic learning?

Tags: optimization, model-evaluation

I am studying metrics for evaluation of various learners in a multilabel classification setting. There seem to be more than 10 various measures, leaving me in some kind of doubt which metric to select, as some do not have intuitive interpretation.

I was thinking of optimizing e.g, TP, TN directly, in a multi-objective setting. Is this sensible?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on your objective.

Comment: Assuming you are given 30 classification tasks, and you are not sure for each one of them what to optimize.

Comment: Are all the classes equally important? Are they all equally represented in the data (proportionally)?

Comment: This varies from dataset to dataset.

Comment: Hard to answer without specific data. Have a look at a proper scoring rules for multiclass prediction, such as Brier score.